# Mulitple directive asking for new isolate scope (directive inside directive)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-scope

i got this Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [otherProgressbar, otherProgressbar (module: toms-standalone)] asking for new/isolated

I am trying to wrap a directive inside a directive

here is my code:

```
declare var otherProgressBar: Function;

class MyProgressBar implements ng.IDirective {

   public scope: any = {
        myTitle: '=',
        myOnCancel : "&",
        myOnClose: "&"
    };

    public template: string = "<other-progressbar title='myTitle'  action-on-close='myOnClose' action-on-cancel='myOnCancel' />";
    public restrict: string = "E";


    public static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive: ng.IDirectiveFactory = () => new MyProgressBar();
        return directive;
    };
}

angular.module("my")
    .directive("myProgressBar", MyProgressBar.factory())
    .directive('otherProgressbar', [otherProgressBar]);
```

The otherProgrssion bar contains a controller and a scope but i am not allowed to changed it in anyway

I simply call My progress bar in my index.html that way

```
`<div>
  <my-progress-bar title="my title" my-on-close="actionOnClose()"/>
</div>`
```

here is my otherProgressBar

```
otherProgressBar = function() {
return {
    restrict:   'E',
    template:   '<div class="otherProgressBar"> ' +
                    '<script type="text/ng-template" id="confirmModal.html">' +
                    '   <div class="modal-header">' +
                    '       <span class=\'modal-title \'>{{title}}</span>' +
                    '   </div>' +
                    '   <div class="modal-body">{{confirmationMessage | translate}}</div>' +
                    '   <div class="footer">' +
                    '        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">{{"CMN_YES" | translate}}</button>' +
                    '        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">{{"CMN_NO" | translate}}</button>' +
                    '   </div>' +
                    '</script>' +
                    '<script type="text/ng-template" id="progressBarModal.html">' +
                    '   <div class="modal-header">' +
                    '       <span class=\'modal-title \'>{{title}}</span>' +
                    '   </div>' +
                    '   <div class="modal-body">' +
                    '       <div class=\'time-label\' ng-show=\'estimatedTime\'>{{"PROGRESS_BAR.TEMPS_ESTIME" | translate}} : {{estimatedTimeLabel}}</div>' +
                    '       <timer class=\'time-label\' interval="1000" language="fr">{{"PROGRESS_BAR.TEMPS_ECOULE" | translate}} : {{minuteUnit}}</timer> ' +
                    '       <uib-progressbar value="percentage" type="{{styleType}}" class=\'progress-striped active\'>{{percentage}}%</uib-progressbar> ' +
                    '       <div class=\'text-center\' ng-bind-html=\'htmlMessage\'></label></div>' +
                    '   </div>' +
                    '   <div class="footer">' +
                    '        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="isCloseButtonDisplayed" type="button" ng-click="close()">{{"PROGRESS_BAR.FERMER" | translate}}</button>' +
                    '        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-show="!isCloseButtonDisplayed" ng-disabled="isCancelButtonDisabled" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">{{"PROGRESS_BAR.ANNULER" | translate}}</button>' +
                    '   </div>' +
                    '</script>' +
                '</div>',
    scope: {
        // Titre de la popin
        title: '=',
        // Indication sur le fait que le traitement peut Ãªtre interrompu avant la fin du traitement
        isStoppable: '=',
        // Indication sur le fait que la fenÃªtre est modale ou non
        isModal: '=',
        // Pourcentage dâ€™avancement Ã  afficher
        percentage: '=',
        // Temps estimÃ© pour le traitement complet
        estimatedTime: '=',
        // Message Ã  afficher sous lâ€™indicateur de progression correspondant :
        // -    Ã  lâ€™action en cours pendant la progression
        // -    Un message dâ€™erreur ou de fin Ã  la fin de la progression
        message: "=",
        // Message Ã  afficher lorsqu'une demande de confirmation est lancÃ©e
        confirmationMessage: "=",
        // Indication sur le fait que le traitement est en erreur
        error:"=",
        // Service Ã  appeler lors du clic sur le bouton Fermer
        actionOnClose: "&",
        // Service Ã  appeler lors du clic sur le bouton Annuler
        actionOnCancel: "&"
    },
    controller: ['$scope', '$uibModal', '$sce', function($scope, $uibModal, $sce) {

        $scope.init = init;
        $scope.init();

        /**
        *   Initialisation avec lancement d'une popup contenant la barre de progression.
        **/
        function init() {

            // Style de la barre de progression par dÃ©faut
            $scope.styleType = 'fwk-info';

            // Est ce que le bouton Annuler est dÃ©sactivÃ©. Si le traitement n'est pas arrÃªtable, le bouton annuler est dÃ©sactivÃ©
            $scope.isCancelButtonDisabled = (!$scope.isStoppable || $scope.isModal) ? true : false;

            // Est ce que le bouton Fermer est affichÃ©. Il n'est pas affichÃ© lorsque le traitement est en cours (c'est le bouton annuler qui est affichÃ©)
            $scope.isCloseButtonDisplayed = false;

            // Si le traitement est stoppable, on ouvre la popup avec la barre de progression, sinon on demande une confirmation Ã  l'utilisateur
            if ($scope.isStoppable) {
                // DÃ©clenchement de l'ouverture de la popup contenant la barre de progression
                openProgressBarModal();
            } else {
                // DÃ©clenchement de l'ouverture de la popup contenant la barre de progression
                openConfirmModal();
            }
        }

        // Mise Ã  jour du label du temps estimÃ©
        $scope.$watch('estimatedTime', function () {
            $scope.estimatedTimeLabel = secondsToHms($scope.estimatedTime);
        });

        // Mise Ã  jour de la bar de progression en fonction du pourcentage
        $scope.$watch('percentage', function () {
            // Lorsque le traitement est terminÃ©, on change le style, on arrÃªte le temps Ã©coulÃ© et on cache le bouton annuler
            if ($scope.percentage >= 100) {
                $scope.styleType = 'fwk-success';
                $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
                $scope.isCloseButtonDisplayed = true;
            }
        });

        // ArrÃªt du traitement si une erreur est dÃ©tectÃ©e
        $scope.$watch('error', function () {
            if ($scope.error) {
                $scope.styleType = 'fwk-error';
                $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
                $scope.isCloseButtonDisplayed = true;
            }
        });

        // Permet d'utiliser l'html de l'attribut message
        $scope.$watch('message', function () {
            $scope.htmlMessage = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.message);
        });

        // Ouverture d'une popup de confirmation
        function openConfirmModal() {
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'confirmModal.html',
                size: 'sm',
                scope : $scope,
                // EmpÃªche la fermeture de la modal sur click en dehors de la modale
                backdrop: 'static',
                controller: ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

                    $scope.ok = function () {
                        $uibModalInstance.close();
                    };
                    $scope.cancel = function () {
                        $scope.actionOnClose();
                        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('close');
                    };
                }]
            }).result.then(function() {
                // DÃ©clenchement de l'ouverture de la popup contenant la barre de progression
                openProgressBarModal();
            });
        }

        // Ouverture d'une popup contenant la barre de progression
        function openProgressBarModal() {
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'progressBarModal.html',
                size: 'sm',
                // Autorise ou non les actions en dehors de la modal
                windowTopClass : !$scope.isModal ? 'not-modal' : '',
                backdrop: !$scope.isModal ? false : 'static',
                // Permet de rendre la modal dÃ©plaÃ§able
                windowClass:'movable-modal',
                scope : $scope,
                controller: ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

                    $scope.cancel = function () {
                        $scope.actionOnCancel();
                        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                    };
                    $scope.close = function () {
                        $scope.actionOnClose();
                        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('close');
                    };
                }]
            }).rendered.then(function() {
                $('.movable-modal').draggable({
                    handle:".modal-header"
                });
            });
        }

        function secondsToHms(d) {
            d = Number(d);
            var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
            var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
            var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

            var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " heure, " : " heures, ") : "";
            var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? " minute, " : " minutes, ") : "";
            var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? " seconde" : " secondes") : "";
            return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
        }
    }]
};
```

};

Can someone explain my mistake please ?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no siaProgressbar in your example. And there's no mention how myProgressBar is being used.

Comment: I edited it adding correcting and adding the missing part

Comment: Where's siaProgressbar from `... otherProgressbar, siaProgressbar ...`? The question cannot be answered if the information in it is incomplete or wrong.

Comment: sorry hope it s good now

Comment: Considering that otherProgressbar is `restrict:   'E'`, `Multiple directives [otherProgressbar, otherProgressbar ...` means that otherProgressbar directive was defined twice, accidentally or not. If it doesn't help and you are sure that it isn't so, please, provide an example that can replicate the error, a fiddle or a plunk.

Comment: Yes! my bad it was declare somwhere else deeply in my code. Thanks you!

Comment: Sure, you're welcome.